# Please suggest a jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, rotator

I'm new in the world of jQuery.

I have below requirements, Could you guys please suggest which jQuery plugin will be useful for me.

Basic Req. : An Image Rotator

1. It should auto-rotate it self....by default time is 5 second....I should be able to change the time
2. Navigation should be there (back / forth)
3. When the mouse hovers over the navigation, it stops animating.

Any help??

Comment: Cycle plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: [GalleryView plugin](https://github.com/tadeck/GalleryView)

Comment: Google it! You should be able to find tons of image rotators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/07/29/content-rotator/

This tutorial is pretty good for what you are trying to do, and it has two examples; one with auto-play, one without it. Used plugins are jQuery Mousewheel Plugin and jScrollPane Plugin.

Comment: This is what I wanted

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_auto.html

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I create Mosaiqy, a jQuery 1.6+ plugin that seems to fit your description (I don't know if I can give a self-promoting link, so just look for "mosaiqy" on google)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is known as Carousal in jquery. There are a tons of plugins available for this and you need to do some customization to make it fit to your needs.

You might look at this [LINK](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/jquery-carousel-plugins-tutorials/)